# Tell TypeScript compiler to omit the | undefined type when using ? in the interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

```
export interface HTMLButtonProps {
  readonly btnType?: BtnType;
}

export const Button = styled.button<HTMLButtonProps>`

  // btnType becomes BtnType | undefined
  ${({ btnType }) => {}
`;

Button.defaultProps = {
  btnType: BtnType.Normal
};
```

When adding the `?` in the prop interface, telling typescript that it's an optional prop, the type instead becomes `BtnType | undefined`. Since I'm trying to make an exhausting switch statement, the `| undefined` keeps messing it up, along with other stuff where I'm forced to use the `as` syntax.

Also, since I'm setting a value in `defaultProp` for the `btnType`, we will assume that the property will never be `undefined` (despite being able to be `undefined` when passed in as a prop, which is OK).

How can I tell typescript that `btnType` is **only** of type `BtnType` **without having to do `as BtnType` everywhere in the code or create a new variable from the existing parameter**?

Comment: I just tried the styled component with switch statement and it looks fine with default state returning null. How does it mess it up?

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı Ah, well we can't use a `default` because the compiler doesn't break when omitting one of the switch cases. So we have ` function foo(param: never) {}` which we call after the switch with `foo(btnType)`. Here the compiler says `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`. If we remove the `?` from the interface then everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood 100% but I couldn't recreate the error here: https://jsfiddle.net/8jxt4om5/ 
But in any case, an if statement checking for undefined before switch statement, should force typescript to figure out proper types after if (btnType === undefined)

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate the issue in question.  You mention a `switch` statement not working; can you include an example?